# graphviz - compare graphic trees

Tags: graphviz, emf-compare

I have to do a job with graphviz. I need to visualize the graphic representation of several trees, but in any case I have to compare two tree to see their differences: something like this, I have tree A and tree B. After create their representation and compare them I need to see only the nodes that don't have in common. Someone told me to use EMF Compare but unfortunately I don't know how to make this plugin accept the extension of graphviz.

Any advice or any other possible solution to face this job?

Regards.

Comment: I am not familiar with graphviz, so I have no idea whether this can be done... a quick googling didn't turn in anything for an export from graphviz to EMF (the underlying modeling technology used by EMF Compare). EMF Compare will allow you to compare EMF models : you need a way to represent your graphviz graphics into such a model before comparing them.

Comment: Yes Kellindil, that's another problem. I couldn't find how to create a model from graphviz and use it with EMF models. That's why I decided to write this question, because I don't have any another idea about how to face this. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given two `.dot` files, `a1.dot`:

```
digraph g1 {
    A -> B -> D -> E
    A -> C -> E
    }
```

... and `a2.dot`:

```
digraph g2 {
    A -> B -> F -> E
    A -> C -> F
    }
```

... you can find the nodes that are different between them as follows:

```
$ dot -Tplain a1.dot | sed -ne 's/^node \([^ ]\+\).*$/\1/p' | sort >a1.nodes
$ dot -Tplain a2.dot | sed -ne 's/^node \([^ ]\+\).*$/\1/p' | sort >a2.nodes
$ diff a1.nodes a2.nodes
4d3
< D
5a5
> F
```

I'm using `sed` to strip the list of node names for each `.dot` file out of the `plain` output from `dot`, sorting the nodes into order and then using `diff` to find the differences. This approach doesn't present the differences graphically, but that is a tricky thing to do at the best of times.

Comment: Man thanks a lot for your trick, actually may be usefull for what I'm doing.

Comment: Since I answered your question, I've been thinking about how to show the differences graphically and I think it should be possible by displaying a merged graph and shading or otherwise annotating each node differently, depending on whether it is common to both graphs, only in graph 1 or only in graph 2. If you'd be interested in this graphical solution, I could explore it. Roughly, I'd start by taking the approach I took in my answer, create a merged graph, then use the `diff` as input to a script that adds different node attributes for the nodes that differ between the original graphs.

Comment: @Simon did you ever build the visual compare mode you talk about here?